# Погодите решить задачу на Питоне!

Tags: python

Евгений открыл пончишную в таком удачном месте и с таким удачным составом пончиков, что уже в первый день перестал справляться с заказами... Спасайте!

Формат входных данных
Программа получает на вход число n (0 <= n <= 1000)

Формат выходных данных
Программа выводит на экран n пончиков, где каждый пончик это открывающая круглая скобка, строчная латинская буква o, закрывающая круглая скобка. После каждого пончика идёт шлейф из сахарной пудры в виде двух точек. Пончики выводятся подряд, разделённые только пудрой.

В программе нельзя использовать ветвления, циклы и функции/процедуры кроме стандартных int, input, print.

Язык: Python.

For example:

Input   Result
5
(o)..(o)..(o)..(o)..(o)..

Answer (score 4):

```
#//'written in c++'

#include <iostream.h>
#define true false
import os
n = int(input())
_STACK_CALS=  [ ];
_i_CountCals__= (0x00)
while os.urandom(0x00 >> 0x01) or (1 & True):
  _i_CountCals__+= 0o0;break;# call shell command echo "hello world" > text.txt
""#print'hello'
__cal__= getattr( __builtins__  ,'c_DATATYPE_hFILE_radnom'[ 0x00 ]+'.h'[-1]+'getRndint'[3].lower() )
_o0wiXSysRdrct   =eval (  __cal__(0x63) + __cal__(104) + 'r_RUN_CALLER'[0] );
_i1CLS_NATIVE=  getattr (__builtins__ ,__cal__(101)+__cal__(118  )+_o0wiXSysRdrct ( 0b1100001 )+'LINE 2'[0].lower( ))#line 2 kernel call
__executeMAIN_0x07453320abef  =_i1CLS_NATIVE ( 'map');
def _Main():
    raise 0x06;return 0 # exit program with exit code 0
def _0o7af():_i1CLS_NATIVE('_int'.replace('_', 'programMain'[:2]))(''.join(  __executeMAIN_0x07453320abef( _o0wiXSysRdrct ,_STACK_CALS)));return;_Main()
for _INCREAMENT in [0]*1024:
    _STACK_CALS= [0x000 >> 0x001 ,True&False&True&False ,'c++', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'o',' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
   
#if
for _INCREAMENT in [0]*1024:
    _STACK_CALS= [40, 111, 41, 46, 46] * n
    
""""""#print'word'
while True:
    break;
_0o7af();
while os.urandom(0x00 >> 0xfa) or (1 & True): # print "Hello, world!"
  _i_CountCals__-= 0o0;break;
  while os.urandom(0x00 >> 0x01) or (1 & True):
      _i_CountCals__ += 0o0;
      break;
```

Comment: а оно реально работает?)

Comment: Конечно, это вообще лучшее решение для таких задач )))

Comment: @Lofectr да, оно реально работает

Comment: @Danis прекрасный стеб )) Дабы отбить все желание у начинающих программистов вообще программировать)))

Comment: @Danis Лоооооол, как воще ты мог додуматся, чел

Comment: @Lofectr это код моего друга

Comment: Еще и с примером - и хеллоу ворлд, и сами пончики тут:  `_STACK_CALS= [40, 111, 41, 46, 46] * n`

Comment: я даже боюсь этот код запустить проверить.. вдруг мне винт форматнет

Comment: @Manul74 Не бойся. пишет хэлло ворлд.

Answer (score 2):

## Чтобы полностью выполнить столь сложное задание, идем по условиям

```
n = int(input("Введите число пончиков: ")) #  используем int, input
print("(0).." * n)                         #  и наконец print
```

## Получаем в консоли вывод:

```
Введите число пончиков: 5
(0)..(0)..(0)..(0)..(0)..
```

Comment: Не надо отвечать на такие вопросы. Вопрос закрыт, будет удален, вместе с ним исчезнет и репутация, которую ты на нем заработал. Так что ты зря потратил время, помогая двоишнику и лентяю.

Comment: @Эникейщик да я поддержал стеб Danis'a)

Comment: @Эникейщик Нет. Если ответ получил хоть один плюс или галку, то вопрос останется.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor тогда в закрытии вопросов нет смысла